# android JSON conversion

Tags: android, arrays, json

i had convert an object in android to JSONobject with this code

```
public JSONObject toJSONMessage() {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_IDAR, this.idAr);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_CREATOR, this.creator);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_PROPRIETAIRE, this.proprietaire);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_TYPEARTEFACT, this.type);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_IDCONTENEUR, this.idConteneur);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_TYPECONTENEUR, this.typeConteneur);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_DATECREATION, this.dateCreation);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_DATEDERNIEREMODIFICATION, this.dateDerniereModification);
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

        for (Modificateurs mod : this.getModificateurs()) {

            JSONObject pnObj = new JSONObject();

            pnObj.put(Artifact.JSON_MODIFICATEUR, mod.getModificateur());

            pnObj.put(Artifact.JSON_DATEMODIFICATION, mod.getDateModification());

            jsonArr.put(pnObj);

        }


        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_MODIFICATEURS, jsonArr);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_TITLE, this.title);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_CONTENU, this.contenu);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}
```

after that i create this function to convert this JSON

```
    public Artifact(JSONObject object) {

    List<Modificateurs> mods = null;
    try {
        this.idAr = object.getString(Artifact.JSON_IDAR);
        this.creator = object.getString(Artifact.JSON_CREATOR);
        this.proprietaire = object.getString(Artifact.JSON_PROPRIETAIRE);
        this.type = object.getString(Artifact.JSON_TYPEARTEFACT);
        this.idConteneur = object.getString(Artifact.JSON_IDCONTENEUR);
        this.typeConteneur = object.getString(Artifact.JSON_TYPECONTENEUR);
        this.dateCreation = object.getString(Artifact.JSON_DATECREATION);
        this.contenu = object.getString(Artifact.JSON_CONTENU);

            this.title = object.getString(Artifact.JSON_TITLE);
            this.dateDerniereModification = object.getString(Artifact.JSON_DATEDERNIEREMODIFICATION);
            JSONArray jsonArr = object.getJSONArray(Artifact.JSON_MODIFICATEURS);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject objet = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                String modificateur = objet.optString(Artifact.JSON_MODIFICATEUR);
                String date = objet.optString(Artifact.JSON_DATEMODIFICATION);
                Modificateurs mod = new Modificateurs(modificateur, date);
                mods.add(mod);

            }
        this.modificateurs=mods;


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

but i can't get the modifiers (modificateurs). and when i want to show the modifiers with a log the app crashes. 
can somebody help me !!

Comment: ok where initializing `mods ` ArrayList before adding `mod ` in it?

Comment: List<Modificateurs> mods = null;
in the constructor